# How to check if a Windows Phone 8.1 device has software or hardware navigation buttons using WP8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to check if a device has Software/Hardware navigation buttons in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Comment: Why does this matter? Is the screen area smaller with software buttons?

Comment: My app is fullscreen, which means the bottom part goes under the soft buttons. I need to detect when it happens.

Comment: What mechanism do you use to go full-screen? Did you look at [`DesiredBoundsMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.desiredboundsmode.aspx)

Comment: I use the followgin method. Unfortunately, the software buttons render on top of the UI. ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.visibleboundschanged.aspx